# Visibility of ID references to entities and aggregate roots

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Suppose there is an entity class `A` like so:

```
class A {
    public Id { get; private set; }
}
```

There is also another entity class `B` which holds a reference to `A`:

```
class B {
    public Id { get; private set; }
    public aId { get; private set; }
}
```

Do guidelines on setting the visibility of ID references to other entities and aggregate roots, such as `aId` in the example above, exist?

Making the entity `Id` `public` with `private` setter seems common practice, but does it imply that making references to other `Id` fields `public` is also prefered? Does a situation exist where such an approach might cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the case of `A.Id`, if something makes that value be defined only after `B` object exists, you won't be able to set it.

So:

- If `A` object always must exist within `B` since the very start of `B`'s life and won't change, you can go for a private setter.
- If `A` object may be set after or change within `B`'s life, either keep the private setter and use another method to set the value (and perform some checks eventually) or let the setter be public.

For `A.Id` field, it will exist since the very start of `A`'s life if you fetch it from your database. However if you're storing in database a new `A` which doesn't have his `Id` yet (it will be set by database), you will need to refetch the `A` created and return it to the upper method so it can use `A.Id`. Or you need to be able to set `A.Id`.

If you really want to enforce something, that would be either `Id` be null or, if it's set, you can't change it anymore. For `A.Id` it depends on the domain's needs.